# MySQL update wp_posts based on wp_meta value?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm creating a custom plug-in for my WordPress site that will run a query. The plugin will run via Wordpress' `wp_schedule_event` function to run daily. This query will act upon the `engine` post type with a custom field named `wpcf-engine-days-to-go`. Currently, my code is not working (see below)

**Goal**
I want to update the `post_status` to 'draft' when a custom field value, `wpcf-engine-days-to-go` reaches '0'. The `post_status` value is located in the `wp_posts` table, and the `wpcf-engine-days-to-go` is located in the `wp_postmeta` table.

**Question**
What is the correct query to update a value in one table based upon another, specifically in my example?

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'tdengine_my_activation');
add_action('tdengine_my_daily_event', 'tdengine_do_this_daily');

function tdengine_my_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'tdengine_my_daily_event');
}

function tdengine_do_this_daily() {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "UPDATE `" . $wpdb->prefix . "posts` SET `post_status`=`draft` WHERE `meta_key` = 'wpcf-engine-days-to-go' = 0 ";
    $wpdb->query($query);
}

register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'tdengine_my_deactivation');

function tdengine_my_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('tdengine_my_daily_event');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll actually want to use the wp_update_post function ( https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post ). This will ensure that all other possible hooks / filters fire as needed, both now and in the future.

Also, WordPress' cron can be a bit funky, since it only fires based on user visits ( when the PHP is run ). If you have a low amount of site traffic, you may have to run an actual server cron job.